# How to extract string between date and first occurrence of digit from nested list in python 3?

Tags: python

How to extract string between date and first occurrence of digit from nested list in python 3?

```
nested_list = [["22/01/2014","a","b5","c","d","1","2.5","3.3"],["e","f"], 
                                   ["25/12/1969","g","h","4","5"],["j","k"]]


def find_in_list_of_list(mylist, char):
  for sub_list in mylist:
    if char in sub_list:
        return (mylist.index(sub_list), sub_list.index(char))
 raise ValueError("'{char}' is not in list".format(char = char))

output = find_in_list_of_list(nested_list, "22/01/2014")
print(output,"first_date_index")
output = find_in_list_of_list(nested_list, "1")
print(output,"first_digit_index")

output = find_in_list_of_list(nested_list, "25/12/1969")
print(output,"second_date_index")
output = find_in_list_of_list(nested_list, "4")
print(output,"second_digit_index")

Expected Output:
[ ["a","b5","c","d"],["g","h"]]
```

Comment: will there be atmost one date and one integer as a string in your examples? also is your date format fixed?

Comment: yes,date format is fixed only@  Devesh Kumar Singh

Comment: and how many dates and integer pairs can occur? will date always be at the first? Please add these details as well

Comment: Is the date always in the first position?

Comment: yes date will always be first .one date and  integer may vary only@Devesh Kumar Singh

Comment: @suba is "b5" correct? Can these values be alphanumeric or you meant `c` ?

Comment: My current approach works fine having `b5`. Just asking as it could simplify my solution @suba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [search()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) function takes the `pattern` and `text` to scan from our main string
and returns a match object when the `pattern` is not found return None.

The `isdigit()` function return `True` if all characters in the string are digits, Otherwise, It returns `False`.

```
import  re
nested_list = [["22/01/2014","a","b5","c","d","1","2.5","3.3"],["e","f"],
                                   ["25/12/1969","g","h","4","i"],["j","k"]]

new_list =[]
for i in nested_list:
    reg = False
    inner_list = []
    for j in i:
        match = re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',j)
        if match is not None:
            reg = True
            continue

        if reg and str.isdigit(j):
            new_list.append(inner_list)
            break
        elif reg and not str.isdigit(j):
            inner_list.append(j)

print(new_list)
```

O/P:

```
[['a', 'b5', 'c', 'd'], ['g', 'h']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) based approach:

```
from itertools import takewhile, islice

[list(takewhile(lambda x: not str.isdigit(x), islice(i,1,None))) for i in nested_list[::2]]
# [['a', 'b5', 'c', 'd'], ['g', 'h']]
```

---

[`takeawhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) from `itertools` is useful for these cases in which we want to return values from an iterable *until a condition is met*, in this case that a given string is not numeric. Hence as soon as the first digit is encountered no more items are taken from the iterable.

I'm also using [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) here to take from the first item onwards in order to skip the initial date.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

reg = re.compile(r'\d{2}/\d{2}\d{4}')

nested_list = [["22/01/2014","a","b5","c","d","1","2.5","3.3"],["e","f"], 
                                   ["25/12/1969","g","h","4","i"],["j","k"]]


for i,_list in enumerate(nested_list):
    d_index=0
    i_index=0
    for j, _str in enumerate(_list):
        if reg.findall(_str) !=[]:
            d_index=j
        else:
            try:
                if float(_str):
                    i_index=j
                    break
            except ValueError:
                pass
    if d_index<i_index:
        print(_list[d_index+1:i_index])
```

output

```
['a', 'b5', 'c', 'd']
['g', 'h']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take, basically tries to parse as date then float, if not then remember the string until float is met.

```
from datetime import datetime
nested_list = [["22/01/2014","a","b5","c","d","1","2.5","3.3"],["e","f"], ["25/12/1969","g","h","4","5"],["j","k"]]

result = []
for in_list in nested_list:
    temp_holder = []
    for string in in_list:
        try:
            datetime.strptime(string, '%d/%m/%Y')
        except:
            try:
                float(string)
                if temp_holder:
                    result.append(temp_holder)
                break
            except:
                temp_holder.append(string)

print(result)
```